# Integrating Square API through Zoho CRM custom connections. How to?

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, crm, zoho

Zoho CRM is asking for these following parameters to create a custom Oauth2.0 connection.
[Here is what Zoho CRM is requesting of me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZetl.png)
Now these seem like common parameters to get an Oauth2.0 exchange. I have access to the authorization code, access token, and refresh token on my server. I have already exchanged them with Square and have them as php variables on my server URL.

My main question is how do I send the tokens to Zoho CRM? After some research, apparently I need a callback URI where I HTTP POST the tokens in headers. After contacting support, Zoho seems to not have a uri where I should post this information. So is Zoho Support in the wrong and missing something? Or is there a universal way to return the access tokens to where the Authorization Server is getting accessed from?